# I like to load my EMFText model in a standalone java applicatio

Tags: dsl, xtext, emftext

I have been looking for a possible answer but nothing yet. I found this piece of code but for Xtext

```
new org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup().setPlatformUri("../");
Injector injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);
resourceSet.addLoadOption(XtextResource.OPTION_RESOLVE_ALL, Boolean.TRUE);
Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(
   URI.createURI("platform:/resource/org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/example.mydsl"), true);
Model model = (Model) resource.getContents().get(0);
```

I need to do exactly the same but using EMFText instead of Xtext. Is that possible?

I would really appreciate any help or answer.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new MydslMetaInformation().registerResourceFactory();
ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(URI.createFileURI("example.mydsl"), true);
Model model = (Model) resource.getContents().get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mirko I'm gonna try.